# I'm testing wordpress, how do I make my own plugin editable after installation?

Tags: wordpress

there are plugins that can be partially edited from the WordPress administrator panel. The plugin I developed does not allow editing the css files for example. I tried this without success

```
add_filter(‘wp_theme_editor_filetypes’, function ($types) {
$types[] = 'css';
$types[] = 'js';
return $types;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Plugins can be edited by any user who can `edit_plugins`, as seen [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5cab65edabee892ec5f0b7d5dda5681f8bcb3558/wp-admin/plugin-editor.php#L17). To adjust the editable plugin file extensions, you can use the [`editable_extensions`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/83c29a4d0869270fd2b298aed19f02f59eb52bcf/wp-admin/includes/file.php#L227) filter.